# Different Method in Relay with two or more switch

Tags: relay

Hmm I cannot specify my question so just take a look my diagram below.

[image]

For my question I want to make full use of a single relay but using two switch to turn on different LED but the source & ground are different. In short I want my circuit design to use less components. Can you give me an idea or hint to get what I want.

Comment: You need a double-switch relay then. It has one coil, but 6 contacts instead of 3.

Comment: I'll try it later

Comment: The switches are really mechanical switches? And the 9V powering the LEDs is really 9 V? Why not just put your mechanical switches directly in series with the LEDs? Then you eliminate the relays altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need isolation you could use a dual opto isolator instead of relays: -

[image]
<sub>(source: [rapidonline.com](https://www.rapidonline.com/catalogueimages/module/M064955L01WD.gif))</sub>

They come in various package sizes of course and most of them will require less current through the LED than what you will likely need for the relay so it's going to be smaller, cheaper and more efficient. Look for a type that has a decent (50% to 500%) CTR (current transfer ratio).

Comment: If you are happy with this answer please consider formally accepting it. That's the payback bit for getting good advice!!